# Is it possible to store large API responses in browser cache for days/weeks using React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, browser-cache

I've got an endpoint (not my own endpoint) that I want to fetch, but the response is multiple MB in size, and can be stored for days or even a week (for the sake of this, let's say I want to store it for 24 hours) without being 'stale'.

If I want to fetch the endpoint and store it in a user's browser cache for a certain amount of days, even if the user closes the browser and comes back the next day, before it attempts to fetch the endpoint again, is that possible? If so, what is the method to do so, and how would I test/verify that it's working as expected?

I know browser local storage can be created manually, but the file is too large for a single key/value and I'd like to avoid that route in favor of something that isn't 'maintained' by my code, something more 'automagic'. I see the fetch has a cache attribute that can be passed, would one of those options do the trick, and what would the full configuration be? Would the endpoint have to be set a certain way to allow me to do so?

**Side/bonus question.** The endpoint mentioned above returns a list of objects with keys/IDs and an value/object of info for each ID. My original thinking was that I would have my back-end server pull/store the response from the large endpoint periodically, and then I would have my own API return a subset of the endpoint's information (only the IDs/info that the user needs). However, it looks like a GET with a body is not part of https standards, and shouldn't be done. So, is there a best practice for how I would pass a list of IDs (100+ IDs, too large to be part of the URL) to my back-end API to allow the API to reduce the response to a subset containing only the info for those IDs? I may want/need to do both in my project.

Example (shortened) endpoint:

```
{
  "1": {
    "status": "Active",
    "age": 40,
    "name": "Foo"
  },
  "2": {
    "status": "Inactive",
    "age": 35,
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  "3": {
    "status": "Inactive",
    "age": 30,
    "name": "Bar"
  },...

}
```

Then I could pass a list i.e. ['1','3'] as part of my fetch that would allow me to use as part of the logic to only get info for 'foo' and 'bar'.

The use of a body in a GET call is rejected by React, and the only other thing I could thing of was to use a  POST with a body that doesn't actually set, but only gets a response. I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you asking multiple questions in a single post so let me try breaking it down a bit here:

1. **Caching Large Responses**:

   - You can use `Cache API` along with `fetch`. Use the `caches` global to cache your request and response objects. Then, on future fetches, you can look in the cache before making a network request.
     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache
   - Note: Caching behavior might also be controlled by the server's HTTP Cache Headers, but the `Cache API` gives you more direct control.
2. **How to Test:**

   - Open the DevTools in your browser, go to the Application tab, and you should see Cache Storage in the sidebar. You can inspect what's stored there.
3. **Endpoint Requirements:**

   - Generally, the endpoint doesn't need to be set in a certain way. It's more about the client-side code properly interacting with the Cache API.
4. **Bonus Question - Passing Large Number of IDs:**

   - Instead of a GET, you can indeed use a POST request to send a large list of IDs in the body. Even though POST is typically for creating resources, it's not unusual to use it for complex queries.
   - Doing a POST for complex queries is totally fine and often recommended. HTTP purists might frown a bit, but it's practical and solves the problem.